# emacs: second toolbar (row)

Tags: emacs, elisp, toolbar

this is my first question, so apologies for breaking any rules.

I've just started writing some functions in elisp to help me navigate certain types of text files more efficiently. To make these accessible, I've added some buttons to the tool-bar. As it's now becoming busy, I'd like to either: 1) move some of these additional buttons to a second line; or 2) instantiate a second tool-bar that could be placed somewhere else in the frame (either under the existing tool-bar, or perhaps vertically along the side where the scrollbar is).

I've searched high and low but am unable to find an existing example of this and, as I don't yet really know what I'm doing, I wonder if somebody has a code snippet from which I might start to hack a solution together.

Many thanks in advance.

System: CentOS 5/6, emacs for linux 23.1

Edit:

Thanks for the comment, William. Here's a simple example representing what my tool-bar code might do:

```
;
; functions used by the toolbar
;
;
```

(defun copy-paste-whole-line ()
  "copies and pastes the whole of the current into a new line underneath"
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (set-mark (point))
  (end-of-line)
  (setq temp (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))
  (message " copying: %s" temp )
  (newline)
  (insert temp))

;
;
; population of the toolbar: 
;
;

(when (find-image '((:type xpm :file "copy_paste_line.xpm")))
  (unless tool-bar-mode (tool-bar-mode 1))
;  (setq tool-bar-map (make-sparse-keymap)) ; <- uncomment this line to have only this button present
  (tool-bar-add-item 
   "copy_paste_line" 
   'copy-paste-whole-line 
   'copy-paste-whole-line 
   :help "copies and pastes the whole of the current line into a new line underneath"))

so, as you can see (actually, I'm not allowed to post images until I have 10 reputation points, so you won't be able to see), the code adds an extra button to the end of the existing tool-bar buttons. I believe this to be a reasonable way to achieve this, but I'm not an experienced elisp programmer, so if you think it's poorly written, please comment - I'd like to understand why... :)

If I only had 1 button, it would be ok like that, however, I have multiple buttons. I would, thus, like to add them to a second instance of a similar tool-bar (or, perhaps a vertical one placed where the scrollbars are).

Thanks again for any input.

Comment: Hey, welcome! You need to include a bit of your current code, how it doesn't work and perhaps describe what you have tried. Have you considered just mapping the functions to a key chord combination instead? The whole point of Emacs (in theory) is so that your hands don't have to move away from the home row.

Comment: I just wanted to comment on the key chord question: long term, I think this is what will end up happening. Short term, this is rather experimental: I'm not sure exactly which functionality will prove to be the most useful, therefore, I don't want to use up "natural" key chords then redefine them etc. The tool-bar is self documenting (image + mouse-over text) and can be quickly reconfigured without too much confusion. Some of my colleagues have expressed interest in what I'm doing and arbitrarily reassigning which keys do what is a recipe for confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Frame parameter `tool-bar-lines` is supposed to control this.  You can, for instance, customize option `default-frames-alist` if you want to change the number of tool-bar rows to 2 or 3 everywhere. Or you can do this on a mode-by-mode or frame-by-frame basis. You can, for instance, use `M-: (set-frame-parameter nil 'tool-bar-lines 3)`.

Depending on your platform (and toolkit), the behavior might be variable.  See the Elisp manual, node `Layout Parameters` and node `Tool Bars`.

Comment: Hello Drew, the OP effectively wants to have multiple tool-bars or rows in the tool-bar. But, the manual says: "On each frame, the frame parameter 'tool-bar-lines' controls how many lines' worth of height to reserve for the tool bar." That means it is only a measure of height (expressed in number of lines, in the default font size I think). Since the tool-bar is c-level I think the OP does not have any chance to get two tool-bars beside the nice triangle in the upper right corner that extends the existing on. At least in cygwin multiple tool-bar rows do not work.

Comment: It depends what you call two toolbars. What constitutes a different/separate toolbar?  What's the difference between two toolbars of one line and one toolbar of two lines?  But yes, there is only one toolbar: it is either on (showing) or not. Its contents can be controlled by program, so software can partition it into, in effect, two parts, as if there were two toolbars. Note too that the OP wrote, in the title: "second toolbar (row)", which seems pretty clear -- it's about having multiple rows.

Comment: Hello Drew, I understand we are speaking about multiple rows in one toolbar. But, is that possible? Did you try it? I've tried it with the setting `(set-frame-parameter nil 'tool-bar-lines 3)` and many icons on two different systems (cygwin and ubuntu) and it did not work. (It should not be necessary because `auto-resize-tool-bars=t` by default.) I've got the impression that it is all about the height of the toolbar **measured** in the height of text lines. I asked Dave Love per e-mail to get some insight here but I did not get feedback till now. Maybe, I am just unlucky with my systems;-).

Comment: I've added an answer with some pictures to show you the result of your suggestion on Ubuntu (same on cygwin). There are also some helpers for easy testing.

Comment: Thanks these pointers. The documentation I found says: "If Emacs is built with GTK or Nextstep, the tool bar can only show one line, so this variable has no effect." My emacs seems to be built on GTK+ and, indeed, I'm unable to obtain any change in behaviour by playing with this variable.

Comment: Hello Drew, finally I tried `emacs-w32`. And this one did really generate 3 button rows. Sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: @Tobias: Hey, no problem. See also [this](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16052) Emacs bug I filed yesterday, which might be somewhat related.

Comment: @user3065349: Consider filing an enhancement request, to get this available on your platform. You do that via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are out of luck. It seems to me that (at least on *ubuntu* and *cygwin*) only one row of buttons in the tool-bar is supported.

Here is what I have tried without luck on both systems:

```
(progn
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'tool-bar-lines 3)
  (loop for i from 1 upto 20 do
    (setcdr tool-bar-map (cons (cadr tool-bar-map) (cdr tool-bar-map)))))
```

The following picture shows what I get:
[image: menu bar of emacs with many buttons]

The other buttons appear in a pull-down menu if you click on the little triangle at the right end of the toolbar:
[image: pull-down menu with the other buttons]

You can restore the old tool-bar with the following commands:

```
(progn
  (setq tool-bar-map (make-sparse-keymap))
  (tool-bar-setup))
```

Finally, I have 3 rows of buttons. This is possible with `emacs-w32`:

[image]

So it **is** the `gtk+` / `nextstep` problem.

Comment: Thank you for the demo: this is a nice confirmation of what I see on my system. Do you think it might be reasonable to add in a second tool-bar in c?